# Include "had"? - Good/Nice evening?

Tags: tense, idiomatic-language

*What happened last night? Trent told me you were in a really bad mood. What's going on? Why couldn't you just have (had) a good/nice evening with him?*

I have two questions:

1. Would it be more natural to include "had"?
2. Do "good" and "nice" mean the same here? Are they equally natural here?

Comment: I'd put adverbial ***just*** in between auxiliary ***have*** and the Past Participle: *Why couldn't you **have just had** a nice evening with him?* Personally, I don't much like *We've had a good evening*, because it clashes with greeting / leave-taking *Good evening*.

Comment: ... but actually, ***pleasant*** is [even more popular](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=had+a+good+evening%2Chad+a+nice+evening%2Chad+a+pleasant+evening&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chad%20a%20good%20evening%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chad%20a%20nice%20evening%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chad%20a%20pleasant%20evening%3B%2Cc0) than ***nice*** in that context.

Comment: Does my post answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be more natural to include "had"?

*`Why couldn't you just have a good/nice evening with him`* means why could you not have a good/nice evening with him in the future.

**Whereas**

*`Why couldn't you just have had a good/nice evening with him`* means why could you not have a good/nice evening with him sometime in the past.

---

> Do "good" and "nice" mean the same here? Are they equally natural here?

A *nice* evening sounds more natural and grammatically correct than a *good* evening.

Comment: So the one with "had" is the more natural choice here?

Comment: @ertariga depends on what you want to say. If you want the past tense, then add 'had'. Otherwise, leave it out.

Comment: @ertariga please accept my answer if it answered your question satisfactorily.